How do I obtain the low energy supergravity actions from the 5 superstring theories?
In Domain-Walls and Gauged Supergravities by T.C. de Witt, there is a small table giving the 5 string theories and each of their effective sugras. I am looking for detailed reviews of how these sugras arise as low energy effective theories of each superstring theory.
.
Is there a direct proof that each of these string theories give rise to the their sugra actions? If so, what are some resources that show this in detail?
If not, how exactly is the correspondence shown and where can I read about how each string theory is connected to its low energy sugra theory?

Some discussion here https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/supergravity-as-the-low-energy-effective-action-of-superstring-m-theory.451296/
